# MySQL IF statement for subquery's

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, subquery

I'm trying to achieve this example in MySQL language (the part of the if-statement).. could anyone try and help me? I've been stuck for days now.

```
SELECT * FROM tblUsers

INNER JOIN
    IF function <= 1
    (
        // SELECTING ALL IF THE USERS FUNCTION TOLERATES IT (HAS PRIVILEGE TO IT)
        SELECT * FROM tblDomains
    )
    ELSE
    (
        // SELECTING A SPECIFIC VALUE
        SELECT * FROM tblDomains WHERE domain = 'example.com'
    )
ON (part continues here, ofcourse)

WHERE username = :name AND password = :password
```

/* UPDATED CODE */

(cough IS NULL instead of = NULL, fixed my issue)

```
SELECT * FROM strix_users
LEFT JOIN strix_userstodomains
ON strix_users.users_id = strix_userstodomains.userstodomains_user
INNER JOIN strix_domains
ON (users_id = 1 AND users_password = 'lol' AND users_function <= 1)
OR (users_id = 1 AND users_password = 'lol' AND users_function > 1 AND userstodomains_domain > 0 AND strix_userstodomains.userstodomains_domain = strix_domains.domain_id)
OR (users_id = 1 AND users_password = 'lol' AND users_function > 1 AND userstodomains_domain = NULL AND domain_name = 'strix-it.local')
```

Comment: This looks wrong. For a user U1 with users_function <= 1 you'd select all their domain associations, say domain D1 and D2. Then you join all domains. If you have only three domains in the table, D1, D2, and D3. Then your result is six rows: U1-D1-D1, U1-D1-D2, U1-D1-D3, U1-D2-D1, U1-D2-D2, U1-D2-D3. That's a mere technical view of course. Maybe you don't store records in strix_userstodomains for users with users_function <= 1? Or is there any other special data constellation you haven't told us yet?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM   tblusers 
       INNER JOIN tbldomains tb 
               ON ( username = :name 
                    AND password = :password 
                    AND function <= 1 ) 
                   OR ( username = :name 
                        AND password = :password 
                        AND domain = 'example.com' 
                        AND function > 1 )
```

Comment: Wise, I didn't see the logic in there. But you made me see it. I'll be updating you! Thanks ;)

Comment: I have been playing around, but couldn't figure out / get it working for what I needed it to be. Could you try and figure out what's wrong for me? I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblusers u INNER JOIN
     tbldomains td 
     ON . . . 
WHERE u.username = :name AND u.password = :password AND
      (COALESCE(@function, 0) <= 1 OR td.domain = 'example.com') ;
```

Note:  You should name variables in such a way that they cannot conflict with column names.  I changed `function` to `@function`.  But this could also be written as something like `v_function`.

Comment: The first example I gave was not exactly the right thing I was searching for (totally my fault). I updated my answer, and I think this may will give you a better overview of what my query needs to do. Thanks in advanced though!